# Right XPath expression for XML when using XML::LibXML

Tags: perl, xpath

I have an issue in arriving at the right xpath to query data from xml. I use use [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) to do this

#### The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<data>
  <header>
    <date>2016-08-07</date>
    <name>Indices Composites</name>
    <version>1.1a</version>
  </header>
  <row>
    <CompositePrice>1.010227784212584</CompositePrice>
    <CompositeSpread>0.002568273865609903</CompositeSpread>
    <Date>2016-08-05</Date>
    <Depth>4</Depth>
    <Heat>0.0201994587386602</Heat>
    <IndexID>ITRAXX-SOVXWES8V1-5Y</IndexID>
    <Maturity>2017-12-20</Maturity>
    <ModelPrice>1.0103988929051526</ModelPrice>
    <ModelSpread>0.002445016658588964</ModelSpread>
    <Name>iTraxx SovX Westn Europe</Name>
    <OnTheRun>Y</OnTheRun>
    <REDCode>5C769MAO9</REDCode>
    <RequestKey>iTraxx SovX Westn Europe|5Y|Y</RequestKey>
    <Series>8</Series>
    <ShortName></ShortName>
    <Term>5Y</Term>
    <Version>1</Version>
  </row>
  <row>
    <CompositePrice>1.0208723593556004</CompositePrice>
    <CompositeSpread>0.006539233068666665</CompositeSpread>
    <Date>2016-08-05</Date>
    <Depth>3</Depth>
    <Heat>0.0307106033333336</Heat>
    <IndexID>ITRAXX-SOVXWES8V1-10Y</IndexID>
    <Maturity>2022-12-20</Maturity>
    <ModelPrice>1.0219657857189512</ModelPrice>
    <ModelSpread>0.006361337372712667</ModelSpread>
    <Name>iTraxx SovX Westn Europe</Name>
    <OnTheRun>Y</OnTheRun>
    <REDCode>5C769MAO9</REDCode>
    <RequestKey>iTraxx SovX Westn Europe|10Y|Y</RequestKey>
    <Series>8</Series>
    <ShortName></ShortName>
    <Term>10Y</Term>
    <Version>1</Version>
  </row>
</data>
```

I need to filter based on the values of certain tags. The code is like below.

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;

my $doc = $parser->parse_file($inputFile);

my @nodes = $doc->findnodes("/data/row/Name[text()='iTraxx SovX Westn Europe']/../Term[text()='5Y']/../OnTheRun[text()='Y']");

print "@nodes \n";
```

The output I get is

```
<OnTheRun>Y</OnTheRun>
```

whereas I would like to get the entire node which satisfies the condition.

Is the XPath expression right here ?

Comment: The `Name` elements in your sample data are identical, and nither of them match your XPath expression.

Comment: my bad. was tinkering with code before I edited. Have updated the right value now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath expressions are very like Linux file paths. If you remove all the predicates from what you have written, you get

```
/data/row/Name/../Term/../OnTheRun
```

You can see here that, from the `row` element, you're descending into `Name` and going back up one level, then into `Term` and going back up one level, and finally into `OnTheRun`, where the expression stops

This is why you see only the value of the `OnTheRun` element, and a simple fix would be to append another `..` path step to get back up to the `row` element that you want to access

This XPath expression works fine

```
/data/row/Name[text()='iTraxx SovX Westn Europe']/../Term[text()='5Y']/../OnTheRun[text()='Y']/..
```

but it is very awkward to read

I think the neatest way to do this is to apply multiple predicates to the main `/data/row` selector, like this

```
/data/row[Name="iTraxx SovX Westn Europe"][Term="5Y"][OnTheRun="Y"]
```

Here's a full program that uses it to process you sample data

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use open IO  => ":encoding(iso-8859-1)";

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => 'indices_composites.xml' );

my @nodes = $doc->findnodes('/data/row[Name="iTraxx SovX Westn Europe"][Term="5Y"][OnTheRun="Y"]');

printf "%d node%s found:\n\n", scalar @nodes, @nodes == 1 ? '' : 's';

print $nodes[0], "\n";
```

#### output

```xml
1 node found:

<row>
    <CompositePrice>1.010227784212584</CompositePrice>
    <CompositeSpread>0.002568273865609903</CompositeSpread>
    <Date>2016-08-05</Date>
    <Depth>4</Depth>
    <Heat>0.0201994587386602</Heat>
    <IndexID>ITRAXX-SOVXWES8V1-5Y</IndexID>
    <Maturity>2017-12-20</Maturity>
    <ModelPrice>1.0103988929051526</ModelPrice>
    <ModelSpread>0.002445016658588964</ModelSpread>
    <Name>iTraxx SovX Westn Europe</Name>
    <OnTheRun>Y</OnTheRun>
    <REDCode>5C769MAO9</REDCode>
    <RequestKey>iTraxx SovX Westn Europe|5Y|Y</RequestKey>
    <Series>8</Series>
    <ShortName/>
    <Term>5Y</Term>
    <Version>1</Version>
  </row>
```

Comment: Instead of `Name/text()='...'`, I'd recommend `Name='...'` which compares the [string value](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes) of the element instead of the contents of its first text child. I'd also use a single predicate with multiple expressions `and`ed together: `/data/row[Name='...' and Term='...' and OnTheRun='Y']`. I think it's a little clearer and it should be slightly more performant.

Comment: thanks Borodin and nwellhof.. this is very helpful!! I also just realised that I could have tested my xpath at http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: @nwellnhof: I agree that it's better to omit `text()` in this case, but the use of `and` is a cosmetic preference. Adding further predicates saves several characters and I think it makes it more readable.